# How can I plot the last 20 points from a file in gnuplot?

Tags: file, gnuplot, gif

I have a big file in gnuplot and I want to plot them as a gif. My file represents the trajectory of 20 particles. I have tried: do for [a=0:70000:10000] {plot 'posicion.dat' i 0:a u 2:3}. This one sohws the completed trajectory but I only want to show the last point of the trajectory of each particle.

How can I plot the last 20 points from a file in gnuplot?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! From your description it is not clear to me how your data is actually structured. I can only guess: three columns and 70000 blocks? Each block separated by two empty lines? Where do I find the trajectory of 1 specific particle out of the 20 particles? Does each block have the same number of lines? Please clarify and give a minimized data example to explain.

Comment: Let's say that we have 2 particles. Each row is referring to one particle: Particle one, row 1; the first column refers to interaction number, second column refers to position axis X, and third column refers to position axis Y, all referred to particle n.1. Next row is referring exactly to same concepts, but to particle n. 2. All above explained refers to first interaction. We repeat same process for multiple interactions. My question is: how can I arrange to make the trajectory to be deleted while it is being updated, in a way that only last 20 points appear, as an example?

Comment: Each row is separated by 2 white  spaces

Comment: still not completely clear... in your case, will row 21 (and rows 41, 61, 81, ...) again contain x,y coordinates of particle 1 but just for a different time? And you basically want to plot rows 69981 to 70000? And I don't understand why you have two empty lines after *every* row? (or do you mean 2 white spaces between the *columns*?)

Comment: Yes it is exactly like that. I mean two empty lines after every row, for me it is easier to make a loop whit those spaces but are not necessary, dont worry about them.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no direct command to plot the last N lines.
If your data doesn't contain double empty lines you could do it with `every` (check `help every`).

You could also make a system call (e.g. under Linux using `tail`) to pass only the last N lines to gnuplot.

However, if you want a platform-independent gnuplot-only solution and if your data consists of lines which are all separated by *two* blank lines you could do the following:

- determine the number of blocks via `stats` stored in the variable `STATS_blocks`
- plot the last M blocks in a loop (keep in mind: numbering starts from 0)

Check `help stats`, `help for` and `help index`.
However, mind the difference: what is called "blocks" together with `every` is not the same what is called "blocks" together with `stats`.

The following example will plot the last 2 lines (blocks).
I hope you can adapt it to your data.

**Script:**

```
### plot the last N blocks
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1   10   11


2   20   21


3   30   31


4   40   41


5   50   51


6   60   61
EOD

stats $Data u 0 nooutput
N = STATS_blocks
M = 2                   # M last values
set offset 10,10,10,10  # just to get some space to the border

plot for [i=1:M] $Data index N-M+i-1 u 2:3 w lp pt 7 lc i ti sprintf("Particle %d",i)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @marcosrequena you're welcome. If this answers your question, please press the check mark next to the answer to indicate that your problem is solved.